# Errno 13 Permission denied for dockerised celery worker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, celery

My celery worker needs to download and save files during handling (preferably inside the container, since I want to upload these files elsewhere and then delete local files). The code works fine until it tries to save and keeps throwing `[Errno 13] Permission denied`. How do I run it with the appropriate rights to save files? I've tried using `chown` command in my dockerfile, but I keep getting the same error.

Currently, dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.5
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD ./celery_main/ /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT celery -A celery_main.celery worker --concurrency=5 --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup --loglevel=INFO
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
        worker:
            build:
                context: .
                dockerfile: dockerfile
            volumes:
                - type: bind
                  source: .
                  target: /app
        ... other services
```

I am currently testing file creation like this:

```
f = open("/app/celery_main/downloads/file.txt", "a")
f.write("We wrote some text")
f.close()
```

Comment: Create a working folder for celery in the Dockerfile with the correct owner and permissions.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried doing that and got the same result. Can you show an example?

Comment: Is everything works if you remove flags `--uid=nobody --gid=nogroup`?

Comment: or just use any folder under `/tmp` to temporarily store your files

Comment: How about you show us how the folder is created and the result?

Comment: @Etoneja it works! It solves my initial problem, but I suppose it is running worker with superuser privileges now.

Comment: @Godfryd if you care about it - you can create user in container, give write permissions to him for your file and define his uid in your run cmd.

Comment: @KlausD. downloads folder is created manually and left empty before running everything. the folder has 775 permissions. I am not sure  what result you are talking about? Celery log? It shows `[Errno 13] Permission denied` error on `f.write("We wrote some text")` line.

Comment: Show us an `ls -l` on the folder!

Comment: @KlausD. `drwxrwxr-x 2 gotf    gotf      4096 Oct 13 12:20 downloads`

Comment: Your folder is not owned by the effective user of celery (`nobody`).